# How to detect if there is new payments

Tags: php, dogecoin

I want to make a cryptocoin payments php in my website, all info already ok. The only problem is, how to know if my member already pay that payments and if already pay update my database,

anybody know about this?

Comment: why question is not clear is not clear for me.